# How to download or know the URL of WSO2 Identity Server's SAML metadata?

Tags: wso2, metadata, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

What would be the URL for the newly set up SAML SSO's metadata URL, or how could I download this in XML format from WSO2 Identity Server (version 4.6.0) acting as IdP?

Thanks,

Tamas

Answer (score 7):

WSO2 Identity server now hosts IDPSSODesriptor metadata file on this URL.
**https://localhost:9443/identity/metadata/saml2**

This feature is available from Identity Server version 5.3 onward.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there is no option to auto-generate metadata files for IS. You have to manually write the metadata file. An example is as follows, taken from [this blog post](http://tanyamadurapperuma.blogspot.com/2013/09/configure-wso2-identity-server-saml2.html).

```
<md:entitydescriptor entityid="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" validuntil="2023-09-23T06:57:15.396Z" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
   <md:idpssodescriptor protocolsupportenumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
       <md:keydescriptor use="signing">
         <ds:keyinfo>
            <ds:x509data>
               <ds:x509certificate>MIICNTCCAZ6gAwIBAgIES343gjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBVMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UE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=</ds:x509certificate>
            </ds:x509data>
         </ds:keyinfo>
      </md:keydescriptor>
     <md:singlelogoutservice binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" responselocation="https://localhost:9443/samlsso">

     <md:singlesignonservice binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso">

     <md:singlesignonservice binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso">
</md:singlesignonservice></md:singlesignonservice></md:singlelogoutservice></md:idpssodescriptor>
</md:entitydescriptor>
```

Comment: Any idea if metadata generation would be available in WSO2IS 5.2 or 5.3?

Comment: In 5.3 you can download the SAML Metadata by going to Identity Providers - Resident -> Inbound Authentication Configuration -> SAML2 Web SSO Configuration.  There is a "Download SAML Metadata" button which will generate the XML for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.. Identity Server does not support to generate a IDP information as metadata file. You may need to create it manually.  But I guess it would be available with a future release. There is an open public jira for this.  You can find a generated SAML2 metadata file from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2013/12/24/how-to-saml-generating-saml-metadata-for-saml2-sso-idp/).  However you may need to configure it according to your configurations. If you have changed your keystore, you need to change the X509 certificate data. And also urls of the samlsso endpoint.  By default saml sso end point is located at `https://localhost:9443/samlsso`. In your service provider config,  you need to configure this url as IDP url (both login and logout). You must provide the wso2carbon certificate in to service provider for validating the signature.

Comment: could you publish a link to the Jira ticket you're referring to?