# Is exchange of metadata required for a working SAML2 connection?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

we are operating as SAML2 Service Provider. A few weeks ago our Certificate expired, so we provided new Metadata to our customers. We told them they have to upload the newdata to their Idp's, because else the SSO won't work anymore because the connection can not be seen as trusted anymore.

Now one customer told us that they didn't exchange the new metadata (they have the old one stored), but the connection still works and their employees are able to login. So my question: Is exchange of metadata required for a working SAML2 connection? Why does it still works with old metadata?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As addressed in the first answer, exchanging metadata is not required, it is an option.

Note that since you're the Service Provider, you're not required (by spec) to sign your messages. The other way around **is** required of course: the IDP needs to sign its messages.

So are you even sure you sign your messages being the SP? Even then, the IDPs implementation may not even able to deal with that (since it is optional) and ignore the signature. A certificate rollover from an SP may not have any impact in those cases.

That may explain the observed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata XML is used for configuring easily both ends of the connection, the identity provider and the service provider. Once they're configured it's no longer required.

For example, WSO2 Identity server doesn't have a way to generate or accept metadata files, yet it's able to manage SAML based sessions. [How to download or know the URL of WSO2 Identity Server's SAML metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625409/how-to-download-or-know-the-url-of-wso2-identity-servers-saml-metadata)

Comment: Thank you. But why is the certificate of the other party then stored in the metadata? I though it will be compared with the incoming request.

Comment: I pressume the certificate is imported to a local keystore to identify that party on subsequent connections. In my experience every value the metadata XML has can be configured manually on both IdPs and SPs. (Shibboleth, WSO2IS, Weblogic, Liferay)...